# How to organize source control for many subprojects?

Tags: git, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree, git-subtree

I am creating a website with web apps within it.  I am now at the stage where I am using phonegap to turn the web apps into mobile apps, but for that I need to make a branch for each app which has the app's directory as the root.

How do I go about creating a branch with a sub directory as the root?

```
root directory
-> app 1
-> app 2
```

Comment: That's not how git branches work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch doesn't work that way. If you want separate source control for each app, you should create a separate repository for each app.

If those subdirectories are a part of a larger project, should be versioned togeter and there's no way to separate them, use [git-submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). There's a [git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) command to help you. But that is a more difficult concept which requires some experience with git, so use separate repos if you can.